# In ZK Can we PostNotifyChange more than one variables

Tags: java, zk, notify

I will want to notify some specific  variables of a class with the help of

> PostNotifyChange

So i was trying

```
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, taskListModel, "model,sequence");
```

It is not working :( Can we PostNotifyChange  more than one variable something like we doing in

> NotifyChange

```
@NotifyChange({ "taskList","sequence" })
```

Is it possible or not with

> PostNotifyChange

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, sorry.

From [the source](https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zkbind/src/org/zkoss/bind/BindUtils.java#L53), it appears `BindUtils` just takes a single `property` name and doesn't try to split it out. Could be a nice feature request.

Comment: Right man if NotifyChange is doing this thing then PostNotiChange also can do this thing