# Is it possible use @NotifyChange instead of BindUtils.postNotifyChange?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, mvvm, zk, zul

I have one confusion use between  @NotifyChange and BindUtils.postNotifyChange ,Why use  this two event .Before i read this question
[In ZK Can we PostNotifyChange more than one variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400964/in-zk-can-we-postnotifychange-more-than-one-variable) .
But i cant understand this question why use this more than one variable.

Here's an example:

```
    @Command
    @NotifyChange({ "folderInfoList", "isDisabled", "selectedFolderInfo" })
    public void refreshFolderInfo() {
        logger.debug("Refresh Icon selected");
        if (isDirty()) {
            Messagebox.show(pageResourceBundle.getText("JS_CONFIRM_DATAMODIFED"), pageResourceBundle.getText("JS_CONFIRM_DATAMODIFED_TYPE"),
                    Messagebox.OK | Messagebox.CANCEL, Messagebox.QUESTION, new EventListener<Event>() {
                        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
                            if (Messagebox.ON_OK.equals(event.getName())) {
                                loadFolderInfoList();
                                selectedFolderInfo = null;
                                BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, FolderInfoEditViewModel.this, "folderInfoList");
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            loadFolderInfoList();
            selectedFolderInfo = null;
        }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me:

I have four question :

1.Why use isDisabled in  @NotifyChange ?

2.Here this method i can use @NotifyChange instead of BindUtils.postNotifyChange ?

3.What is the difference between  @NotifyChange and BindUtils.postNotifyChange ?

4.I want to use only one event between this two  @NotifyChange and BindUtils.postNotifyChange in  method .Is it possible for this method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If the variable associated with `"isDisabled"` is not changed in any case by this call, you don't need to.
But maybe it is changed inside `loadFolderInfoList()`
2) You can imagine that a `@NotifyChange({"arg1","arg2",...,"argN"})` is the same as

```
for(String arg : args){ 
  BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, refToClassCalledFrom, arg); 
}
```

3) But you can call `BindUtils.postNotifyChange(...)` from everywhere as long as you got a reference to the VM.
4) To me it looks like this code is from a nested class of `FolderInfoEditViewModel`, that it self is is VM as well as `FolderInfoEditViewModel`.
In this case the `@NotifyChage(...)` is invoked for the nested class but

```
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, FolderInfoEditViewModel.this, "folderInfoList");
```

refers to it's outer class `FolderInfoEditViewModel` and that can only be archived this way.